# React stay on current page after refresh

Tags: reactjs, state, page-refresh

I have 3 Tables in my app that are displayed one at a time `Branches`, `Services` and `Guichets`.

```
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            Branches: [],
            Services: [],
            Guichets: [],
            context: "Branches",
            Branche: '',
            isHidden: true
        }
    }
```

It knows which table to display based on a context state that is initially set to `Branches` and each time the state changes the `context` goes through a switch clause to know which table to display in the new render instance.

This is the code to add a new row into the `Services` table for example:

```
  OnSubmitService = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/AddService", {
      method: "post",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
      body: JSON.stringify({
        REFService: this.state.REFService,
        LibService: this.state.LibService,
        REFBranche: this.props.branche
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(message => {
      if (message === "ServiceEX"){
        this.setState({ErrorMessage: "Le service existe déja"})
      } else {
        window.location.reload(false)
      }
    })
  }
```

So the problem is that in order for the new `row` that I just inserted to be displayed a `refresh` is needed, you can see I'm using `window.location.reload(false)` for that but it takes me back to the `Branches` table and I have to manually go back to the `Services` table to see the new row.
I'm too far ahead to start using `React Router` now, it would break a lot of things in the app so is there a way I can set the `context` for the next the refresh so it knows to stay on the table I was in before refreshing?

Comment: Why would refresh be needed to see new data?

Comment: So that the component will re-render and excute the fetch call for the new set of data in the database.

Comment: Why don't you just make a call to the database without reloading? It's really uncommon to reload react apps